# Is there a good book on designing for electrical safety with AC mains power?

Tags: ac, safety, mains

Is there a good book on how to design for electrical safety, particularly when using AC/mains power? I have look on Amazon without finding anything that seemed appropriate. This topic is largely ignored or else glossed over in at most a chapter in the books I have. I had expected more coverage, particularly in books on power amplifiers and design of power supplies. The best coverage that I have found is in the ARRL Handbook.

Comment: Designing for safety or designing to meet particular safety agency standards? For power supplies it's mostly making sure that the isolation is adequate (eg. layout, opto ratings, SMPS transformer design) and that parts which 'see' the mains are rated appropriately.

Comment: One valuable resource if you are planning to market your product is to purchase copies of all the standards you plan to conform to (and any other similar ones you can cheaply obtain) and trying to make a note of all the requirements you must comply with and then use standard engineering principles to solve the restrictions (there is no magic, just a bit of art involved).  There must be some books out there but a lot is experience, reverse engineering and fault finding of previous designs.  If you just learn from a book the results often look unpleasant and are expensive to make and repair.